# What is the Form "On_Load" equivalent for Controls?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I have a listBox that I would like to carry out a method when its loaded up, although I can't use the Form "On_Load" trigger, since the ListBox is within a TabControl.

Is there a way of getting a method to execute when the object initializes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @SLaks stated, you could put in your class's constructor.  However, if what you want to prepare relies on other elements in the form, you can add to the event handler queue at the end of a form loading, but before its actually presented to the user.

In the constructor code of your form (not the designer code), add to the load event, then add your own custom function

```
public partial class frmYourForm : Form
{
    public frmYourForm()
    {
       Load += YourPreparationHandler;
    }

    private void YourPreparationHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do you code to prepare list, combos, query, bind, whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: Forgive my lack of knowledge, but where are the constructors found? program.cs?

Comment: Using Visual Studio, in your Solution Explorer where it shows all the different forms, classes, etc in your projects... Right click on the form in question and click "View Code".  That should bring you to the "Your Code" partial class version of the form vs the DESIGNER version of code which should be left alone.

Answer (score 3):

The closest analog for controls is the [`HandleCreated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handlecreated.aspx) event. This will fire when the underlying control handle is created, which is slightly before the `Loaded` event of the parent window would fire.

Answer (score 1):

Have the same problem, the previous answers apply well, for a single case.

But, I require to do something in most controls, in several forms, in an app.
Solved by using an interface:

```
interface IOnLoad
{
  void OnLoad();
}
```

And added to descendant control:

```
public partial class MyButton : Button, IOnLoad
{
  void OnLoad() { // call "OnLoadDelegate" }
}

public partial class MyForm : Form
{

  public void MyForm_Load(...) {
    foreach(Control eachControl in Controls) {
      if (eachControl is IOnLoad) {
        IOnLoad eachOnLoadControl = (IOnLoad)eachControl;
        eachOnLoadControl.OnLoad();
      }
    } // foreach
  }
} // class
```

Its more complex, but it suit my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e). However, it triggers during design time too. You can override it too.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the [`HandleCreated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handlecreated.aspx) event?

Answer (score -1):

You can just put your code in the constructor.

You usually don't need to wait for any initialization.

Comment: While this would be my preferred method, there are unavoidable circumstances in WinForms where you must execute the code after there's a valid control handle in order to get proper behavior.

Comment: Could you provide an example please?

Comment: (-1) Because in .NET controls, some code cannot apply until the constructor is finished, that's why there are several methods like Form_Load(), Form_Active(), Form_Shown()