# C# - Loading methods within the constructor

Tags: c#, .net, windows, constructor

Could someone explain why executing this method (in the constructor) throws a syntax error:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        Load += YourPreparationHandler;
    }

    private void YourPreparationHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button22_Click(sender, e);
    }
}
```

> The name 'button22_Click' does not
>   exist in the current context

Comment: Uhm, I'm going to comment even though the answer is pretty obvious, since I believe the problem isn't what you state it is, or the code isn't what you show it is. The method `button22_Click` does not exist in the current context (ie. reachable from the point where you call it.) Have you verified that the method is actually there? In the code in the question it surely isn't.

Comment: Forgive this, but does "button22_Click" exist in the class?

Comment: Jezz, who's downvoting the answers that seem correct here?

Comment: The code here is mostly a copy+paste from an answer to a previous question. The part that's not working is the part that Mike added. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442487/what-is-the-form-on-load-equivalent-for-controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually in the constructor there is something like this:

```
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
}
```

Form classes are set up as partial classes.  This is because in Visual Studio when you drag and drop components onto a form, behind the scenes VS is updateing the designer file with your updates.

So, you will have

Form1.cs

Form1.Designer.cs

and possibly

Form1.xx.resx (if you have globalization in place)

If you look at the designer file you will see something like this that Visual Studio is code generating:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.buttonTest = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.textBoxPW = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.textBoxOutput = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // buttonTest
```

I bet the designer file is missing, messed up, or InitializeComponent was removed by accident.  In any case, the object (button_22) doesn't exist or is not referenced so you will not be able to raise a click event on it.

Answer (score 5):

Is `button22_Click` a member of `Form1`? Check that method exists, the error is pretty self explanatory.

Comment: There is no reason to downvote this answer. Upvoted to compensate.

Comment: I don't see why anyone would want to downvote this either. There are some strange people on this planet....

Answer (score 4):

Is `button22_Click` defined anywhere? That would be the problem if it isn't.

Comment: There is no reason to downvote this answer. Upvoted to compensate.

Comment: At the very least, it deserves the same score at Matthew's answer - they're synonymous. :P

Comment: Yeah, but Matthew was first. Or well, Lasse was first, in his comment.